# login prompt while accessing IIS site

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis

I am facing an issue with one of my website where all users are continuously prompted for entering a domain password and login. The popup doesn't go away even after entering the correct password. If I add the user in administrator group of the IIS server it starts working.

Anonymous login is disabled and windows login is the only authentication mode which is enabled. The users access the site while logged into domain.

How can I fix the login prompt popup when the user is already connected to the domain?

Comment: Did you have a question, or did you just want to share that story with us?

Comment: Thanks David, my question is how can I fix the login prompt popup when the user is already connected to the domain. I am sorry don't have much experience with IIS.

Comment: What is the authentication configuration in your web.config?

Comment: Try to sniff the HTTP authentication headers with [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) for example to point out which kind of 401 headers you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Joe, one of the sub folder was not having Permission. Used fiddler to figure that out.